# Maven Dependencies creation from ant lib/jar folder

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I am trying to migrate a legacy project from Ant to Maven. Main problem which I am facing is that there are multiple jars in the lib folders which we earlier used for Ant. Now as there are 200 plus jar and I am sure there might be some duplicate as well. Is there a way to generate a pom.xml file from the list of jars. Only option which I see now is searching them one by one on Maven repo and adding them one by one. Is there an easier way to do this ?

Thanks,
Amol

Comment: Having a single module about 200+ jar's sounds like this jar contains too much.. Yes and doing this manually makes your sure you have checked each of those jar's if they are really necessary...which is also a step of the migration (remove the unused one's)...

Comment: Yep working through those. Also breaking the module but still I will have to add around 100+ jars in pom and have to get their groupid etc. from maven manually. Thats what I was looking for. If there is something which returns me the details. Like an API I can use that

Comment: Take a look into the answer which @JF Meier wrote...would make it easier...

Answer (score 0):

I worked through a similar problem (the jars for Ant were not part of the svn/git but on a network drive). I wrote a script that roughly did the following:

1. Enumerate all the jar files that are dependencies (or that may be dependencies)
2. Take their SHA1 values and search for them on MavenCentral. If the jars were directly copied from there, you will find them. But beware: There can be different versions of the same jar with the same version number.
3. Take classes from the jars and search for them in MavenCentral (classname search). This allows you to determine a good number of groupId:artifactId. Versions are tricky because they share the same classes.
4. Use the filename and its ending (like junit-4.12.jar) to guess artifacts from MavenCentral.

This way you get an approximate mapping between your jars and MavenCentral. This obviously has to be corrected manually, and you will also probably find jars that are not from MavenCentral and have to be added to your Maven repo.

If you have the full list, create a pom.xml from them. Try to build your project. Add missing dependencies if it does not build.

In the end, use `dependency:analyze` https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html to eliminate the unnecessary dependencies in your pom.